# How to use an XML string to find certain element values in php?

Tags: php, xml

How to use an XML string to find its certain element values?
i used this code:

```
    10: $php_var = json_decode($json, 1);
    11  $serializer=new XML_Serializer();
    12: if($serializer->serialize($php_var))
    13: xml_string=htmlspecialchars($serializer->getSerializedData()); 
    14: echo $xml_string;
    15: $xml_obj = new DOMDocument();
    16: $xml_obj->loadXML($xml_string);
    17: $urls=$xml_obj->getElementsByTagName('url');
```

but it doesnt work and i got a Warning: `DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1 in /var/www/seo-tool/get_details.php on line 15`

Comment: smells like invalid XML to me. Provide your `$xml_string` please

Comment: <array> <responseData> <results> <XML_Serializer_Tag> <GsearchResultClass></GsearchResultClass> <unescapedUrl></unescapedUrl><url></url><visibleUrl></visibleUrl><cacheUrl></cacheUrl> <title></title> <titleNoFormatting></titleNoFormatting> <content></content></XML_Serializer_Tag></results><cursor><pages> <XML_Serializer_Tag> <start>0</start><label></label> </XML_Serializer_Tag> </pages> <estimatedResultCount>1</estimatedResultCount> <currentPageIndex>0</currentPageIndex> <moreResultsUrl></moreResultsUrl> </cursor> </responseData> <responseDetails /> <responseStatus>200</responseStatus> </array>

Comment: this is my xml string.Actually it is was json and i serialized it to convert it to xml format.

Comment: Really now. Is this **the same garbage you've posted twice before**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's that `htmlspecialchars()`? that function converts all the `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;` and the xml is no longer xml.

Remove that call. if you want to echo the XML, do `echo htmlspecialchars($xml_string)` but don't store it in the variable.

---

Old was:
The XML you posted seems to be valid.

But you are missing the XML declaration, at the beginning of the string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Comment: But the serialized string is coming without this starting tag <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

Comment: This is my code:$php_var = json_decode($json, 1);
 $serializer=new XML_Serializer();
 if($serializer->serialize($php_var))
 $xml_string=htmlspecialchars($serializer->getSerializedData());
 echo $xml_string;

Comment: hy i added the first tag  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> but there is no use.

Comment: wait, what's that htmlspecialchars()? that function converts all the < and > to &lt; and &gt; and the xml is no longer xml. remove that call. if you want to echo the xml, do "echo htmlspecialchars($xml_string)" but don't store it in the variable.